# Github não sobe meu site corretamente com Bootstrap 4

Tags: css3, twitter-bootstrap, github

Boa noite pessoal, estou tentando subir meu site no GITHUB que estou elaborando para estudos, porém não está funcionando corretamente parece que as configurações do Bootstrap e CSS não funcionam quando espelho ele com o aplicativo do github desktop, alguém sabe onde estou errando?

Veja como está ficando o site: https://wilkerbn.github.io/Curso/

Veja os arquivos no repositório: https://github.com/Wilkerbn/Curso

Se alguém souber onde estou errando por gentileza me ajude.

Grato.

Answer (score 1):

Seu caminho está errado para acessar o CSS

Repare que no seu HTML a referência está assim

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/compiler/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/compiler/style.css">
```

Mas no repositório o caminho é outro

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wilkerbn/Curso/master/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css

> node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Vc pode seguir essa mesma ideia para arrumar todos esse erros 404...**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Certo, atualizei os links agora o problema está outro:

Refused to apply style from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wilkerbn/Curso/master/node_modules/bootstrap/compiler/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Sabe me dizer como corrigir?

Comment: @WilkerBruno acredito que seja pq o MIME Type do .CSS está errado. Normalmente o css é incluido no documento dessa forma `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="meu.css" />` repare que o type dele é ` type="text/css"`. Então acredito que de alguma forma essa pode ser seu problema por ai... Mas se o problema do carregamento foi resolvido, considere marcar a resposta como aceita e depois vc abre outra pergunta mais especificamente sobre o MIME Type para outras pessoas também poderem te ajudar